# System.DmlException: Insert failed. STRING_TOO_LONG, Body: data value too large

Tags: apex, string, dmlexception

I have a string which has a length of `89308` which represents a PDF document.

I want to store this data into a `ContentVersion` like this:

```
ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
    versionData = Blob.valueOf(label),
    title = 'PDF Label',
    pathOnClient = '/Label-' + DateTime.now().getTime() + '.pdf',
    FirstPublishLocationId = relatedID);

insert contentVersion;
```

But when I insert the `ContentVersion` record I get this error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 2; first error: STRING_TOO_LONG, Body: data value too large: ... (max length=32768): [Body__c]

But if I look at the SOAP API reference for [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) it says:

> The maximum file size you can upload via the SOAP API is 50 MB.

Which means I can store a lot more than `89308` characters.

And the Field Reference for [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ContentVersion.htm) does **not** state a limit.

**Questions**

1. How can I get around this DML insert limitation such that I can store the content?

Comment: The error message says `Body__c`. Do you have a trigger involved that might be copying the content to another sObject? What's the full stack trace?

Comment: @DavidReed no triggers on `ContentVersion`. I will add more stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@DavidReed made the key break through - by noticing that the error related to `Body__c`.

After storing the data into the `ContentVersion` I was logging the REST request into another object which had a field `Body__c` which had a max length of `32768`, and this was throwing the exception.

Because the content being stored into the `ContentVersion` and the Log was identical, I did not realise.

mea culpa.